# audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

I am trying to `segue` to the next view at the end of a short music clip. There aren't any errors but when I run it, the `NSLog` message never appears and the segue never happens. Why doesn't the `delegate` know when the audio ends?

This is the .h file:

```
@interface RecordingViewController : UIViewController 
<AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    NSArray *recordingsArray;
    int randomizedArtist;

}
```

Here's some code from the `viewDidLoad`:

```
// set self as AVAudioPlayerDelegate
[player setDelegate:self];

// prep Audio Player
@try {
    NSError *myError;

    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:recordingsArray[randomizedArtist] ofType:@"mp3"];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]  error:&myError];

    if (!player) {
        NSLog(@"viewDidLoad:error %@", [myError localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"viewDidLoad:failure reason %@", [myError localizedFailureReason]);
        NSLog(@"viewDidLoad:recovery option %@", [myError localizedRecoveryOptions]);
        NSLog(@"viewDidLoad:recovery suggestions %@", [myError localizedRecoverySuggestion]);
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception){

    NSLog(@"Exception %@ occurred", exception.name);
    NSLog(@"Exception reason %@", exception.reason);
    NSLog(@"Exception userInfo %@", exception.userInfo);

    // make pop up alert

}
@finally{

    NSLog(@"Finally on reading URL file called");

}

[player prepareToPlay];
```

Here is where I call the player to start playing:

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
    [player play];
}
```

And here is where I call the segue:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"Player did finish playing");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"quizVCSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: add some additional code

Comment: Set delegate inside try catch block where you allocate the player instance. As it is now, your delegate is set before allocation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code if its work

```
@interface ViewController()..,AVAudioPlayerDelegate
```

Allocate the AVPlayer

```
 NSError *error;
_audioPlayerRecord = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    _audioPlayerRecord.delegate = self;
    [_audioPlayerRecord prepareToPlay];
}
```

and
     `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Comment: if user does not implement the `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
` framework also the delegate won't call

Comment: Yes we have to Import it I forget to add that

Comment: It worked! I don't know why repositioning it from before the try-catch-finally to during the finally worked, but it did. Thank you!